# Cannot find element with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to automate some testing using Selenium and Python. I've created a suite using the Selenium IDE and it's working perfectly.

I'm now trying to re-create that suite within a Python script and hit a problem.

For one element, Selenium always returns a 'cannot find' error from within Python, despite being perfectly ok via the IDE.

Things I've tried so far:

- Using XPATH instead of the ID
- Using an implicit wait
- Using the `is_element_present` function produced by exporting to Python from the IDE
- Using WebDriverWait

Here's the html definition from the IDE that works fine:

```
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>id=b_s2_l1s2_ctl00_1_Editor</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>sendKeysAndWait</td>
    <td>id=b_s2_l1s2_ctl00_1_Editor</td>
    <td>Yes${KEY_TAB}</td>
</tr>
```

Python script using implicit wait. All works fine until the offending element in the last line:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.implicitly_wait(30)
browser.get('<my url>')
browser.maximize_window()

browser.find_element_by_id('ctl05_name').send_keys('<name>')
browser.find_element_by_id('ctl05_client').send_keys('<client>')
browser.find_element_by_id('ctl05_password').send_keys('<password>')
browser.find_element_by_id('ctl05_next').click()

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[10]/div/div[2]').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[2]/span/div/div/div/div/div/span/div/div/ul/li/div/div[3]').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//li[9]/div/div[3]').click()

browser.find_element_by_id('b_s2_l1s2_ctl00_1_Editor').send_keys('Yes', Keys.TAB)
```

and using explicit waits. Again, all is ok until the last element:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('<url>')
browser.maximize_window()

browser.find_element_by_id('ctl05_name').send_keys('<name>')
browser.find_element_by_id('ctl05_client').send_keys('<client>')
browser.find_element_by_id('ctl05_password').send_keys('<password>')
browser.find_element_by_id('ctl05_next').click()

element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[10]/div/div[2]'))
)
element.click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[2]/span/div/div/div/div/div/span/div/div/ul/li/div/div[3]').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//li[9]/div/div[3]').click()

element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "b_s2_l1s2_ctl00_1_Editor"))
)
element.send_keys('Yes', Keys.TAB)
```

Any ideas on what to try next?

Comment: what about posting the code you tried so far that didn't work, and what do you mean with "works fine via html"?

Comment: OK, I'll pull together the various things I've tried. 'Works via html' refers to the html definition used by the IDE

Comment: the HTML code that your working your automation on would be helpful as well, and then at what command in your code does Selenium not find the element? Is it already when trying to find the id 'ctl05_name'?

Comment: it's the last line that fails

Comment: The html is enormous - a web client for a commercial product. The element with id 'b_s2_l1s2_ctl00_1_Editor' definitely exists and the IDE has no trouble finding it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted! The element was within a frame which was within an iframe. The IDE sorts that out by itself, but the python needs to do so explicitly.